# What are these plants that look like bamboo?

Tags: identification, trees, leaves

What is this tree? I’m just wondering so I know if it’s grows big to block a view.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the bamboo and some other shrub that was planted between fences?  Which is your home?  What view is it you want to block?  Or it is a view you don't want blocked?

Comment: I’m looking at the bamboo in the first pic. Looking if it’s a trouble weed and also how big it gets.

Comment: Sorry, I think it’s bamboo...  not sure myself.

Comment: Bamboo might be a good thing for that 'spot'.  Some bamboo stays at 5' high, others 6', others 12' others 25+ feet.  I've read that bamboo comes up the diameter it will always be.  If this guy is 1" in diameter he might be able to provide screening.  Architectural screens and screening works very well, fast, doesn't take up too much room.  Is your home on the right?  Are you screening a hot tub or swimming pool?  What is happening with that giant tree?  Which way does the wind blow?  Grins!

Comment: Bamboo likes more sun but it looks happy enough.  Have you ever given it any fertilizer?  Do you ever water it?  What is that other shrub, it looks like a rather great ornamental?  Bamboo does well in pots.  You could get some of the same bamboo and make a few large pots of it to thicken the screen of bamboo and bring the screen closer to what you want to screen, doesn't have to have much height to provide privacy right now this season.

Comment: Any idea what type of bamboo this is, and if it’s invasive? This isn’t mine.

Comment: So you live on the left?  It might not be bamboo, could be nandina or heavenly bamboo that isn't bamboo.  Close ups of leaves.  Please.  More information, I have lots of experience with battling neighbors and plants and stuff.  Bamboo is invasive, depends on how it has been planted and whether it has been sequestered or not with metal siding down into the ground.  Is this your big tree, Simon?  That is the tree I am a bit more worried about.  There is a name for trees like this; widow makers.  Healthy, thinned...should be fine for awhile.  Let's talk home insurance?

Comment: To try to ID the bamboo, we would need better lit  photos so details can be seen clearly...

Comment: Added a couple of photos.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types (species) of bamboo, but usually they are bought from the garden centers (assuming that bamboo is not native to your region), which limits the number of available species.

One popular species is [*Fargesia* 'Rufa'](http://www.bamboogarden.com/Fargesia%20sp.%20%27Rufa%27.htm) which is a clumping bamboo and is therefore not invasive. It is hard to tell if this species is the one your neighbor has planted. You might wanna talk to your neighbor, if possible, and ask him/her if this is clumping bamboo or of the invasive type.